# Why isn't this reading the dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm requesting a JSON resource from the Reddit API and I've manage to parse it into this dictionary stored in the response variable:

```
{'json': {'errors': [], 'data': {'modhash': 'foo', 'cookie': 'bar'}}}
```

I then run `modhash = response.get('modhash')` to parse the modhash entry (`foo` in this example), but it's returning a value of `None`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key `'modhash'` is stored in a sub-sub-dictionary, so to get it you have to write:

```
    modhash = response['json']['data'].get('modhash')
```